# Salesforce IOS error requested scope is not available

Tags: iphone, oauth, salesforce

I have started a new project from salesforce template o XCODE, then I created a fresh remote acces application on Salesforce web.

Then I replaced the RemoteAccessConsumerKey and the OAuthRedirectURI on the AppDelegate.

When I run the application it says, invalid_scope -> requested scope is not available.

my scope params are:

```
[NSSet setWithObjects:@"visualforce",@"api",nil] ;
```

Comment: Are you using the latest template from the git repository? The downloadable zip file on the developer blog is no longer up to date.

Comment: @Sukitha Udugamasooriya, Did you solve scope problem? as I'm also having the same problem. Can you please help me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What is the callback URL from your Remote Access object?
One guess is that your callback URL begins with something like "https" rather than a custom scheme like "testsfdc" (which is what the template app provides). Try using a custom scheme instead ie "myapp:///mobilesdk/detect/oauth/done"

Comment: @Exactly! I have put an https address.

Comment: @thrusty, even my redirectURI started with https:... like https://localhost:44300/signin-salesforce is it cause for this scope issue. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this on a legacy hybrid app I had to update for iOS10. I noticed that the Salesforce SDK persists its initial oAuth endpoint data. So switching from sandbox to production will return the above error.

Solved by deleting the app completely and compiling with production config.

Hope this helps.